# Javascript - DOMParser.parseFromString()getElementById().innerHTML displays values for blank tags

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have below responseText whose xml content is stored in ID "XMLResponseText". When I parse this using `DOMParser.parseFromString` and tried to get the `innerHTML`, blank tags are not displayed correctly.

Example - The tag "County" has no value. It displays as self closing tag. `< county />`. See below

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body text="#000000">
<ProcessTable id="XMLResponseText"><?xml version="1.0"?>
<nib:ProcessRequestResponse xmlns:nib="http://schemas.embarq.com/NIBSAdapter" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ZipCode><ZipDetail><Branch>Las Vegas</Branch><Service>SWWVLVWWNV</Service><City>LAS VEGAS</City><State>NV</State><County/><Zip>89166</Zip><Territory>T-LVWWNV05</Territory><Warehouse>LVWWNVAA</Warehouse><RATType>DIALTONE</RATType></ZipDetail></ZipCode></nib:ProcessRequestResponse>
</ProcessTable>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I have below code.

```
var parser=new DOMParser();

var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(objHTTP.responseText, "text/html");

var XMLResponseTextVal = xmlDoc.getElementById("XMLResponseText").innerHTML;
```

`alert(XMLResponseTextVal)` displays "County" with values in it.

```
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<nib:processrequestresponse xmlns:nib="http://schemas.embarq.com/NIBSAdapter" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <zipcode>
        <zipdetail>
            <branch>Las Vegas</branch>
            <service>SWWVLVWWNV</service>
            <city>LAS VEGAS</city>
            <state>NV</state>
            <county>
                <zip>89166</zip>
                <territory>T-LVWWNV05</territory>
                <warehouse>LVWWNVAA</warehouse>
                <rattype>DIALTONE</rattype>
            </county>
        </zipdetail>
    </zipcode>
</nib:processrequestresponse>
```

Comment: That's obviously not HTML, so why do you treat it like HTML? That's not even [valid XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags).

Comment: I think the OP inserted spaces in order to display the greater than signs -- not realising that formatting as code solves that issue.

Comment: Can you extend the response text *including* the `XMLResponseText` element, and not only the XML content? This is important, as the behaviour you describe typically occurs when the XML is not correctly escaped or not correctly embedded in a CDATA tag. (And when you update, make sure you format that content as code -- see my update)

Comment: Even after extending response text, I get same. I have updated the description with responseText that includes XMLResponseText element. Also if you see, XMLResponseTextVal displays everything in lowercase.

Comment: @trincot, I see this issue only for nodes that does not have value. I have another responseText which contains - <Title/><Phone>702-455-0242</Phone><BusinessInd>V</BusinessInd>... When I do Domparser.parsefromstring().getelementbyid().innerHTML, its displays as - <title>&lt;Phone&gt;702-455-0242&lt;/Phone&gt;&lt;BusinessInd&gt;V&lt;/BusinessInd&gt

Comment: Is the html exactly like you put it in the question (the first code block)?

Comment: @trincot yes it is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your HTML does not escape the raw XML content, and so the rules of HTML apply to it. When content is not to be parsed as HTML, at least the `<` and `&` symbols should be escaped (into HTML entities), and the content should be read using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`:

```js
var responseText = `<html>
<head>
</head>
<body text="#000000">
<ProcessTable id="XMLResponseText">&lt;?xml version="1.0"?>
&lt;nib:ProcessRequestResponse xmlns:nib="http://schemas.embarq.com/NIBSAdapter" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    &lt;ZipCode>&lt;ZipDetail>&lt;Branch>Las Vegas&lt;/Branch>&lt;Service>SWWVLVWWNV&lt;/Service>&lt;City>LAS VEGAS&lt;/City>&lt;State>NV&lt;/State>&lt;County/>&lt;Zip>89166&lt;/Zip>&lt;Territory>T-LVWWNV05&lt;/Territory>&lt;Warehouse>LVWWNVAA&lt;/Warehouse>&lt;RATType>DIALTONE&lt;/RATType>&lt;/ZipDetail>&lt;/ZipCode>&lt;/nib:ProcessRequestResponse>
</ProcessTable>
</body>
</html>`;


var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(responseText, "text/html");
var XMLResponseTextVal = xmlDoc.getElementById("XMLResponseText").textContent;
console.log(XMLResponseTextVal);
```

The server that you make the request to should adapt this. If this is not possible, then don't parse it as HTML, but extract the part that interests you from the raw response text:

```js
var responseText = `<html>
<head>
</head>
<body text="#000000">
<ProcessTable id="XMLResponseText"><?xml version="1.0"?>
<nib:ProcessRequestResponse xmlns:nib="http://schemas.embarq.com/NIBSAdapter" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ZipCode><ZipDetail><Branch>Las Vegas</Branch><Service>SWWVLVWWNV</Service><City>LAS VEGAS</City><State>NV</State><County/><Zip>89166</Zip><Territory>T-LVWWNV05</Territory><Warehouse>LVWWNVAA</Warehouse><RATType>DIALTONE</RATType></ZipDetail></ZipCode></nib:ProcessRequestResponse>
</ProcessTable>
</body>
</html>`;

var XMLResponseTextVal = responseText.split(/<\/?ProcessTable[^>]*>/g)[1];

console.log(XMLResponseTextVal);
```

Comment: Do you mean that I must first perform escape on my responseText and then parsefromstring ? Also please let me know how to wrap in a CDATA construct

Comment: No, I mean that the server is returning something that is not properly escaped. This must be fixed at the server side.

Comment: How do I fix that ? Or Can I try CDATA wrap if that can be done through script ?

Comment: If you don't control the server, contact the administrator. CDATA was a bad idea, I removed it from my answer.

Comment: Server is the one where this script is running or the server to which my application connect through API ? I have control to my application server. Please let me know how to fix if its from my app server

Comment: Its the server that sends this HTML response that needs to adapt. I will add another possibility if you have no control over what you receive.

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thank you

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: Yes I tried today and it works. Thanks much :)